# FATAL EXCEPTION: main with android and eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Im making a simple GPS/Google maps based app in android and i was about finished with it when it just throws up this horrible error. I really dont know where to start with trying to debug this aswell because it doesnt stop at any breakpoints i put in the main activity and im not massively familiar with android, java or eclipse.
So as annoying as it is im just going to dump the whole main file in here

Basically, the point of the app is that it'll find out where you are and then you can choose to bring up a wikipedia article based on where you are

edit: and ive tried restarting the emulator,eclipse, cleaning and rebuilding

Any help will be massively appreciated

Logcat:

```
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): Process: com.example.playservicestest, PID: 1846
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.playservicestest/com.example.playservicestest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.example.playservicestest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:101)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     ... 11 more
```

source:

```
package com.example.playservicestest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Map globals
    LocationManager mLocationManager ;
    Criteria mCriteria = new Criteria();
    String mBestProvider;
    Location mLocation;

    GoogleMap mMap;
    GeoPoint mMapPosition;

    //String globals
    String localityString;
    String countryString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Widget assigning
        TextView tLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Location_text);


        //Location Initialising
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mBestProvider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(mCriteria, false);
        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mBestProvider);

        mCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        mCriteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        mCriteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        mCriteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        mCriteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
        mCriteria.setCostAllowed(true);

        localityString = "Nothing yet!";
        countryString = "Nothing yet!";


        int iminTime = 2000;
        int iminDistance = 50;
        LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() 
        {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
            {
                // Update application based on new location.
                updateLocation(location);
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
            {
                // Update application if provider disabled.
                updateLocation(null);
            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
            {
                // Update application if provider enabled.
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras)
            {
                // Update application if provider hardware status changed.
            }
        };

        updateLocation(mLocation);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mBestProvider, iminTime, iminDistance, mLocationListener);

        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment)).getMap();

        LatLng CurrPos = new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(),mLocation.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CurrPos, 13));

        Button bCurrentPosition = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Current_pos);
        bCurrentPosition.setOnClickListener(CurrentPositionListener);

        Button bChangePosition = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Change_pos);
        bChangePosition.setOnClickListener(ChangePositionListener);
    }


    public void callIntent(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = null;
        if(view.getId()==R.id.Find_info)
        {
            if(localityString!="Somewhere in")
            {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+localityString));
            }
            else if(countryString!="the middle of the ocean")
            {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+countryString));
            }
            else
            {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean"));
            }
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    View.OnClickListener CurrentPositionListener = new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            findCurrentPosition();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener ChangePositionListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setTargetPosition();
        }
    };

    public void updateLocation(Location location)
    {
        TextView mtextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Location_text);

        if(location !=null)
        {
            mtextview.setText("Lat: "+location.getLatitude()+"\nLong: "+location.getLongitude()+"\n");
        }
        else
        {
            mtextview.setText("No Location found");
        }
    }

    public void findCurrentPosition()
    {
        if(mLocation !=null)
        {
            LatLng CurrPos = new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(),mLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CurrPos, 5.0f));

            double lat = mLocation.getLatitude();
            double lng = mLocation.getLongitude();

            LatLng Point = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            setAddressMarker(Point);    
        }
    }

    public void setTargetPosition()
    {
        TextView tLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Location_text);

        CameraPosition TargetPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();

        double lat = TargetPosition.target.latitude;
        double lng = TargetPosition.target.longitude;

        LatLng Point = new LatLng(lat,lng);

        setAddressMarker(Point);    
    }

    void setAddressMarker(LatLng Point)
    {
        TextView tLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Location_text);

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);


        try{
            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(Point.latitude, Point.longitude, 1);
            //targetAddress.getLocale()

            if(addresses.size()>0)
            {
                Address targetAddress = addresses.get(0);   

                if(targetAddress.getLocality()!=null)
                {
                    localityString = targetAddress.getLocality();
                }
                else
                {
                    localityString = "Somewhere in";
                }

                if(targetAddress.getCountryName()!=null)
                {
                    countryString = targetAddress.getCountryName();
                }
                else
                {
                    countryString = "the middle of the ocean";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                localityString = "Somewhere in";
                countryString = "the middle of the ocean";
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tLocationText.setText("You're target is: "+ localityString +" "+ countryString);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title(localityString)
        .snippet(countryString)
        .position(Point));
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.playservicestest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyA4XfZDxD_pzC4wyF4nsQPjvMZIl3V-Mew"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.playservicestest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: provide a stack trace! nobody is going to search through your whole code!

Comment: please post exception trace from logcat

Comment: could you post the manifest.xml please?

Comment: Line numbers could help, look this error in the stacktrace (it seems to be the source of the error, knowing the variable in this line we can trace better where the problem is) :Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 03:41:45.283: E/AndroidRuntime(1846):     at com.example.playservicestest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:101)

Comment: I cant really find anything wrong with line 101. it's just this:
LatLng CurrPos = new LatLng(mLocation.getLatitude(),mLocation.getLongitude());
and i havent changed this for a while

Comment: I can't make tests now, but could you put a check before line 101 checking if mLocation == null ?. It could be that the class is still null, and you are trying to access a method of the class that is still void (null).

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!
One day when i can actually program well i will repay this community!

Comment: The stack trace is pretty descriptive: `NullPointerException`... When you see this, the first thing you need to check is, is any of the objects referenced at that line a `null` object (at runtime)? *Standard debugging practice, if you ask me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is the location, check some examples from internet of how to work with it. Like this https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/311/tutorial_android_location_service_example